# nginx disallow direct file access, allow domain only

Tags: nginx

I need advise how to implement the following rules with NGINX:

If the user requests domain.com (or any domain) directly, send him to a node.js application (proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;), but if the user requests any file or other URL directly, which is not just the clear top domain name, serve /img.png file.

Any ideas how to implement that?

Comment: what config have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
if ($request_uri != "/") {
  rewrite ^ /img.png last;
}

location /img.png {
  internal;
  root /path/to/image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a declarative approach:

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

try_files /img.png =404;
```